# how do I get subset dicts from of list of dicts?

Tags: ansible

for example I have list like:

```
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}]
```

The dict has 3 keys, but I only want 2 of the keys, so I want to filter the list and dict to create:

```
[{'a': 1, 'c': 3}, {'a': 1, 'c': 3}, {'a': 1, 'c': 3}]
```

How can I do this with ansible/jinjia2 filter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are more options. Given the lists

```yaml
  l1:
    - {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
    - {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
    - {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
  l2: [a, c]
```

- Use the filter [*ansible.utils.keep_keys*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/utils/keep_keys_filter.html#ansible-utils-keep-keys-filter-keep-specific-keys-from-a-data-recursively). Declare the variable

```yaml
  l3: "{{ l1|ansible.utils.keep_keys(target=l2) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  l3:
    - {a: 1, c: 3}
    - {a: 1, c: 3}
    - {a: 1, c: 3}
```

- The iteration below gives the same result

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        l3: "{{ l3|d([]) + [dict(_keys|zip(_vals))] }}"
      loop: "{{ l1 }}"
      vars:
        _keys: "{{ l2 }}"
        _vals: "{{ l2|map('extract', item) }}"
```

- The next option is to (mis)use [*omit*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#making-variables-optional). The task below gives the same result

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        l3: "{{ l1|map('combine', {'b': omit}) }}"
```

- This can be generalized by iteration of the rejected keys

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        l3: "{{ l3|d(l1)|map('combine', {item: omit}) }}"
      loop: "{{ l1.0.keys()|difference(l2) }}"
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    l1:
      - {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
      - {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
      - {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
    l2: [a, c]

    l3: "{{ l1|ansible.utils.keep_keys(target=l2) }}"

  tasks:

    - block:

        - debug:
            var: l3|to_yaml

        - set_fact:
            l3: "{{ l3 + [dict(_keys|zip(_vals))] }}"
          loop: "{{ l1 }}"
          vars:
            l3: []
            _keys: "{{ l2 }}"
            _vals: "{{ l2|map('extract', item) }}"
        - debug:
            var: l3|to_yaml

        - set_fact:
            l3: "{{ l1|map('combine', {'b': omit}) }}"
        - debug:
            var: l3|to_yaml

        - set_fact:
            l3: "{{ l3|map('combine', {item: omit}) }}"
          loop: "{{ l1.0.keys()|difference(l2) }}"
          vars:
            l3: "{{ l1 }}"
        - debug:
            var: l3|to_yaml

      run_once: true
```

Comment: `d(l1)` is `default(l1)`; `d()` is an alias for `default()`. I didn't know that. Thanks!